# giving a list variables value then changing the variable without affecting the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to give a variable value to a lists and changing the variable then adding it to the list, wile keeping the values.

```
a = []

for i in range(0,10):
    a.append(i)

print(i)
```

that is what I tried

I expected

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

but I got

```
9
```

Comment: Uh..... the list is `a`, not `i`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above- print your list:

```
a=[]

for i in range(0,10):
    a.append(i)
print(a)
```